# What does GraphQL do with the return value from a resolver?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

I recently started learning GraphQL and I've discovered a situation that I'm unable to explain.

Take the following example

```
var {ApolloServer, gql} = require("apollo-server")

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Query {
        test: type1!
    }
    type type1 {
        value: String!
    }
`;

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        test: (parent) => {
            console.log(parent)
            return "How does my query still work?!"
        }

    },
    type1: {
        value: (parent) => {
            console.log(parent)
            return "hello!"
        }

    }
}

const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers })
server.listen(8080).then(({url}) => console.log(`server stated on ${url}`))
```

Under normal circumstances, GraphQL resolves the a query from the outside to the inside and will use the most specific resolver it has for a given field until all fields have been resolved.

What I find perplexing about this example is what exactly happens to the string that I return from my top level resolver.

This query

```
query {
    test {
        value
  }
}
```

yields the result

```
{
  "data": {
    "test": {
      "value": "hello!"
    }
  }
}
```

Given the above example, I would fully expect my GraphQL server to throw an error since my top level resolver returns a `String` instead of the `type1` that the schema asks for.

My question is basically, what is my server doing with the values that my resolvers return? Clearly, if I return a `String` in my top level resolver, something pretty big must be happening for that to translate into an `Object` for the query response.

Comment: @xadm I’ll try it tomorrow. I tried logging args after that comment told me to and it very little to illuminate the situation. args will be an empty object because there are no parameters being passed into the query. Unless I’m totally misunderstanding something about how GraphQL is implemented, you’re going to need to be a little more specific.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66114816/6124657  ... search for some tutorials about "how it works"

Comment: @xadm Respectfully, this comment is extremely unhelpful. If your goal is to actually help me understand this concept or even answer my question, then you should spend more than two seconds actually creating an answer. The code I’m running here is simple enough that you could run it yourself and even make the necessary changes to it to illustrate whatever you’re trying to show me. Telling someone who is asking a specific question about a specific tool to “just watch some tutorials” is about the most useless piece of advice you could possibly provide.

Comment: @xadm If I felt that watching tutorials alone could actually answer my question then I would happily do it, but having already watched multiple hours worth of tutorials on GraphQL, I’m at a place now where I’m pretty confident it will not lead to an answer to this specific question. If you cannot provide an actual answer or even explain what you mean in your comment, then there’s no point in you commenting at all.

Comment: what is logged ? what is expected by server? how it's related?  log `info`

Comment: @xadm As I pointed out before, if you log args it outputs an empty object for each resolver. This is exactly what one would expect since I’m not providing any parameters to the query. What exactly is it that you’re trying to show here?

Comment: `info`, not `args` https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#resolver-arguments ... resolver doesn't return what it wants then continues

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same thing today. I didn't understand what's the need for providing a return type if you can return anything like a string for a specific type definition?

So if I see how REST API is done then I can think that the return type is for API documentation and for the application that is consuming it which is hinted in the HTTP content-type header. This tells you an example the return type is of type 'application/json' but not the schema - maybe there is a different header for it? or the application can get it from some kind of API documentation like Swagger.

Useful Swagger doc snippet from https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/

```
paths:
  /users:
    get:
      summary: Get all users
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A list of users
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ArrayOfUsers'
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ArrayOfUsers'
            text/plain:
              schema:
                type: string
```

PS: Very new to the web domain. Kindly let me know of any incorrect assumptions.